# Impossible to show all records if parameter is not given in Power Bi Report Builder

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've been struggling to make it work. I have a dataset with column Country and each record has its own country. I've also created a parameter @Country which is a blank input. What I want to do is to show all records from dataset if parameter is left empty and show records matching country when it is given by user. So far everything works whenever I input a country BUT when I leave it blank then no records are being shown. How can I fix it?

Snippets of code I've tried, ever one with the same result.

```
FILTER('Dataset', ISBLANK(@Country) || 'Dataset'[Country] = @Country))

FILTER('Dataset', IF(ISBLANK(@Country), 1, 'Dataset'[Country] = @Country))

FILTER('Dataset', IF(ISBLANK(@Country), 'Dataset'[Country], 'Dataset'[Country] = @Country))

FILTER('Dataset', IF(NOT(ISBLANK(@Country)), 'Dataset'[Country] = @Country, 1))
```

Comment: Can you share a minimum reproducible example .pbix? I'm not sure what kind of parameter you have created.

Comment: How do you initialoze @Country. As David mentioned it can be that you have a problem with  `ISBLANK(@Country)` statment, so check it.